Discount rate for Credit risk calculation
For ECL calculation within CECL, all future loan cash flows need to be discounted, it is stated that,
Several methods are accepted for the calculation of expected credit losses, discounted cash flows being one them. Other accepted methods (such as loss-rate method) implicitly consider the time value of money.
What exactly is the loss-rate method and how does it consider time value of money?

Can you please add the source for your quotes.

@DimitriVulis https://www.openriskmanual.org/wiki/IFRS_9_versus_CECL

thank you @DanielLobo . But it doesn't say "loan rate", rather "loss rate".

I corrected the typo. Thank you! But what is loss-rate how how does is related to time value of money

Googling loss rate, rather than loan rate, finds https://www.wipfli.com/-/media/wipfli/collateral/fi-cecl-methodologies-whitepaper.pdf which sounds helpful.
